# c++ thread issue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to create a thread in c++ with this code:

```
pthread_t mythread;
void* f (void*) = MyClass::myfunction;
pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, &f, NULL);
```

It's not working. Any idea what's wrong ?

myfunction is of type:

```
void* MyClass::myfunction(void* argv);
```

The error returned is:

```
error: declaration of ‘void* Class::f(void*)’ has ‘extern’ and is initialized

error: invalid pure specifier (only ‘= 0’ is allowed) before ‘::’ token

error: function ‘void* Class::f(void*)’ is initialized like a variable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're declaring `f` as a function rather than a function pointer. It should be:

```
void* (*f) (void*) = &MyClass::myfunction;
      ^^^^

pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, f, NULL);
                                ^ no & since it's already a pointer
```

This will also only work if `myfunction` is static, since you can't convert a pointer-to-member-function to a pointer-to-function.

If you do need to the thread to execute a non-static member function on a particular object, then one approach is to write a static wrapper taking the object as an argument:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void start_thread() {
        // Pass "this" to the thread we're creating
        pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, &MyClass::thread_entry, this);
    }
private:
    static void * thread_entry(void * object) {
        // Call the member function on the object passed to the thread
        return static_cast<MyClass*>(object)->thread();
    }
    void * thread() {
        // do the interesting stuff, with access to the member variables
    }
};
```

Of course, these days there's a standard thread library which removes the need for this dance:

```
std::thread thread(&MyClass::thread, this);
```

Comment: Okay, but if the function isn't static, and I'm within a member of MyClass, what syntax should I use ?

Comment: @bob: I've updated the answer to describe how to use a non-static member function.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the usage of std::thread. I'm using a old compiler so it doesn't work for me, but probably will for most others reading this. I think I didn't make myself clear regarding my use case, sorry. What I meant is that the 3 lines of my initial post are part of a (non static) member function of MyClass(). So I want to create a thread from within an instance of MyClass. And the 'main' of the thread (called 'myfunction') should also be in MyClass, so that it can access the variables of the instance this thread was created in.

Comment: @bob: Yes, that's what my example does. `pthread_create` passes `this` as the argument to the static thread entry function; that calls the non-static thread function on that object; and so that function runs on the thread, and has access to the members of the object the thread was created by. I've made it clearer that these are all member functions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think your answer solves my issue. I'm just struggling a little to adapt it to my real case. I get this error: error: cannot declare member function static void* MyClass::thread_entry(void*)’ to have static linkage. Where might it come from ?

Comment: @bob: If you're definining the function outside the class, then don't put `static` on that definition, only on the declaration inside the class.

Answer (score 2):

Pthreads expects a **function pointer**, and with classes, you can only point to a static method using a function pointer.

If you'd like to call **a specific method of a class** on **a specific object**, you need two separate parts of data:

- pointer to a class method (don't confuse them with function pointers)
- pointer to an object

These two joined together can be informally called a *delegate*.

---

PThreads is a C library, and to interoperate with it, you need a little workaround:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
    void *(*start_routine)(void*),
    void *arg);
```

We're going to wrap the class method in a static class method, to be able to  pass it as parameter `start_routine`, and we're going to pass the pointer to the object itself as `arg`.

See the code:

```
struct Foo {

    // wrapper method
    static void* threadStartingPoint(void* obj) {
        return ((Foo)obj)->threadFunc();
    }

    // your target method itself
    void* threadFunc() {
        // this is where you do your logic
    }
}
```

Such workaround allows you to use `pthread_create(thread, attr, Foo::threadStartingPoint, someObject)`.

---

Note that if you are lucky enough to have a modern compiler which supports `std::thread`, you can use that instead of pthreads and have the code much simpler - you just need to create a `std::function` object and pass it to `std::thread`'s constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You simple can't do what you are trying to do - a member function (UNLESS it is static) needs an object in which to be called - that is the process starting the thread can't just call MyClass::f() because it needs to call something.f() - and it doesn;t know what something is.

Typically one gets around this by defining a static member function which takes the object as a parameter and then calls the member function on that object.